# C#/WPF intellisense order by type VS2012

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, code-intelligence

The order is usually alphabetical:
[image]

I want the order will be by **Type**, ie: poperty first and after that attached property and so on...

There is any way to do that?

Comment: you might find what you're looking for in the custom edit here http://help.syncfusion.com/ug/wpf/edit/default.htm#!documents/459intellisensesupport.htm

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is currently a selection tool (choosing what you want to show by default), perhaps they will implement this.

Intellisense does however realise what you use the most, and usually keys towards that, but other than that there's no solution really.

Ofcourse if you want to play around, you can find intellisense in Tools>Options>Text Editor> c#> Intellisense.

Edit - for the comment given with the link, that would mean entirely mapping his own intellisense, rather than just opting for things to show in order